# Windows IOT Broadcast Webcam

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, iot

I would like to make a Webcam Broadcast app on my Raspberry pi 2 running Windows IOT.

As we see in the Windows [IOT samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit), you can record video but you can't

broadcast the video on network (as wifi).
In this code, I use the MediaCapture class to get the video stream.

```
            // this._mediaCapture is a MediaCapture variable, initialized
        // there is a MediaElement item to see the video
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

        // starting recording to stream
        await this._mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(profile,stream);
        // stopping recording to access the stream
        await this._mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();
        //linking the stream to a MediaElement item to see the video
        await stream.FlushAsync();
        MediaElement.SetSource(stream, "video / mp4");
        MediaElement.Play();
        return stream;
```

The problem is that we have to call the StopRecordAsync method to access the stream.
With a timer, we  can record a 5s (for example) vidéo, call the StopRecordAsync method, flush the stream and do it in a loop but.

Comment: I am just wondering, are you able to use any other USB UVC cameras other than those receommended by Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have detailed solution but a hint. I think recording is not what you want. You just want to grab and upload the preview stream from veiwfinder. For that you need to send the preview stream to a customized sink. In your case that will be a cyclic buffer receiving from media capture and sending them to server.

You should check the method:

```
MediaCapture.StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync()
```